# Ada: windows installation

Tags: windows-xp, installation, ada

When downloading the tar file from AdaCore for the GNAT compiler (the libre version), I noticed that there are two exe files for installation purposes:

win32ada-gpl-2010.exe of size 2.67 MB

and

gnat-gpl-2010-i686-pc-mingw32-bin.exe of size 70.2 MB

In the folder containing the second one, there are instructions for the installation and it installs the GPS editor as well.

I have Win XP and chose to install the second exe file. Now I'm thinking that the second one is for a MINGW installation whereas the first exe file is for a native Windows installation. But I can't find information for this. Which of the two exe files is for a normal Windows installation?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Win32Ada](http://archive.adaic.com/tools/bindings/win32ada/win32ada.html) I believe is just a set of Win32 bindings for Ada. That's why it is so much smaller.

You might download that if you want to do a lot of Win32 systems programming or GUI work, and don't have a set of higher-level bindings (eg: [GTKAda](http://libre.adacore.com/libre/tools/gtkada/))

Comment: Thanks. I have installed the MINGW exe version just to be sure that I don't miss some "important" components later.

Comment: @yCalleecharan - gnat-gpl-2010-i686-pc-mingw32-bin.exe is the compiler (and GPS, and a bunch of other tools), and that you have to have. You may be able to get away without win32ada-gpl-2010.exe, depending on what you plan to do. (Doesn't the installation of the win32ada package ask you to acknowledge that you have a licensed Win32 SDK?)

Comment: Thanks. To install, I just double-clicked on the file gnat-gpl-2010-i686-pc-mingw32-bin.exe. The compiler and GPS are installed. I am not asked if I have the licensed Win32 SDK.